# Can two different addresses be assigned to a single smart contract?

Tags: solidity, smart-contract-wallets

For example, if I want to send money to my smart contract at address A.

And then send money to the same smart contract at address B.

Answer (score 1):

**Each smart contract has a unique address.**

To be able to send money to your smart contract A using another address B, you can deploy a forwarding smart contract(address B) where you define the callback function as follow :

```
function () payable {
      if (msg.value > 0) {
          if (!AddressA.send(msg.value)) throw; 
      }
}
```

this fallback function will be triggered once the contract B receives funds. The contract B needs to have enough gas to perform the transfer.